# SVG animations inside g element slow in chrome

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

This had me baffled for hours!

I have an SVG animation which was stuttering in Chrome but smooth in Safari - the animation is a few delayed `transform: scale(n)` on `path` elements.

I noticed if these were wrapped in a `g` element, the animation was slow in Chrome, but if this was removed the animation was smooth.

I also noticed if a `transform: translate(0, 0)` was added to the `g` element it runs smooth again in Chrome.

Here's an example https://codepen.io/andrewmacmurray/pen/gOmXJqL

My questions are:

1. Does this happen to anyone else? (I'm using chrome 90)
2. If so, why does this happen?

Comment: Please try changing 1000ms to 1s

Comment: Maybe worth reporting here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: I confirm this problem still exists in September 2022. Solved it using this hack: https://aerotwist.com/blog/on-translate3d-and-layer-creation-hacks/